# Axios in Sapper requesting twice?

Tags: javascript, jwt, axios, sapper, svelte-3

I'm using `axios` to send request in and outside `preload`. But i don't understand that for some reason my backend is complaining JWT must be provided. I'm using the same backend with another frontend (Svelte only with Axios) and no complains there. But in Sapper when I'm requesting with axios with credentials (yes with them). I'm getting jwt must be provided.

When I logged request Urls at backend I came to know that Sapper is sending request URLs twice to backend one with credentials and one without them which results in JWT must be provided. I'm pretty sure that the request with credentials is from axios but the without credentials one request is coming from magic. Where is this magic happening? and why?

```js
<script context="module">

  import axios from 'axios'

  const ax = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:7000',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  })

  export async function preload (page) {
    const {data} = await ax.get(`/profile/${page.query.type}`)
    let profiles = data
    return { profiles, page }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues (*outside of preload*) and my problem was that Sappers server-side code was posting first request and Sappers client-side code was posting second request (*it's because Sapper has server-side rendering if I understand it correctly and Sapper is running your code too before sending it to browser where it runs second time*).

Can you add some if statement that is checking `if (process.browser) { [...] }` (or the existence of `window` or some other browser-exclusive variable) before axios request?

Server-sided code will obviously not have access to cookies or localStorage from users browser so JWT will be empty.